# Java - set object attribute to null

Tags: java, null

I try to implement an specification diagram. There are 3 classes: Company, Department, Employee.

- Employee has name, salary, department.
- Every Department has a Company, name, employees (0..n) - I made a LinkedList for that -, and a Manager of the Employee Type which can be manager in only one department.
- Departments can have subdepartments of the Department Type - I made a LinkedList for that, too. And a "different" constructor for subdepartments.
- Every Company has a name.

Now I have a questions and an issue:

- QUESTION: Since a manager can be manager in only one department, I check in `setManager` if any department has this manager as manager. If so, then I return. Is this a correct way to do this? I thought about a boolean `isManager` but there's nothing like that in the specification.
- ISSUE: If I remove an Employee from a departments list with `removeEmployee` I set the Department variable of the Employee in the same method to null. But if I try to get the name of the Department in which the Employee is, I still get the Department and not null.

That's how the `removeEmployee` of the Department class code looks like:

```
public void removeEmployee(Employee e) {  
    employees.remove(e);  
    e.setDepartment(null);  
}
```

In the main method I do this to check if the Department of the Employee is null:

```
    departmentName.employees.remove(employeeName);
    System.out.println(employeeName.getDepartment().getName());
```

The Output should be ***null***, but I get ***departmentName***.
He's removed from the ***employees*** list of the Department but to set the Department of the Employee to ***null*** fails.

I would be happy if you could answer my question and help me with my issue.

I could also upload the diagram and my three classes to let you check but I don't think you want to waste your time.

Kind regards,
Newb

Comment: Can you share the code for `Employee`? It's hard to answer without seeing the full details.

Comment: `departmentName.employees.remove(employeeName);` - You aren't really calling `removeEmployee` here.

Comment: I'm an idiot. BackSlash, that was the problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `employees` is some sort of `List<Employee>` and is `public`.

This makes it possible to call `departmentName.employees.remove(employeeName);` which does not call `setDepartment(null)`, it would be better to declare `employees` as `private`, and only use the `public removeEmployee()` method to remove the employees.

This way you avoid removing employees in any other way than the way you've defined (this is called encapsulation).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to replace line with invoking remove method, because you don't invoke your method. Instead of that you invoke Collection method.

It should looks like this:

```
ObjectName.removeEmployee(employee);
```